# Is it possible to use PreferenceFragmentCompat on Android Wear (and have correct styling)?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-appcompat, preferencefragment

I have a Wear app that needs to show preferences, to that effect, I'm currently using a `PreferenceFragment`, and this works normally.

Now in the interest of using the Architecture components, I'm migrating my app to use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` and the appcompat `Fragment`s instead of the SDK ones.   And therefore I have to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` instead of `PreferenceFragment`.

When I do that I have non Android Wear styling, as seen on the screenshot.

[image: Before / After]

As you can see, on the right image,

- There is no title
- The SwitchPreference doesn't work as expected (no widget + ellipsis)
- There are separators where there shouldn't be any
- There's not enough padding top and bottom so the first and last items are cropped
- The margin between the widget and the text is too big

Is this even doable, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73183201

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm using support Fragments so I need to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. Dialog preferences also don't work because they require an AppCompat theme. So what are we supposed to do? Use the deprecated `android.app.Fragment`?

Comment: No, so far, I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Google recently released the emulator for Android 11 and the Preferences still look bad. Our only hope is that it's fixed in Android 12.